# Migrate a Heroku (Node.js) server to Amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, heroku, dialogflow-es

Currently I have a Heroku server running some Node.js code. I use this server as a webhook to receive a POST request from API.AI (Dialogflow) information.

Before starting to research and all the funcionability of Amazon S3, I wanted to see if is possible migrate this Heroku server to Amazon S3 and maintain the API.AI webhook functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

[Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) is an object storage service. It can be used to [host static websites](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html), but not websites that require any server-side logic. (Amazon does offer other services that can run Node.js code, like [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).)

Comment: I see Chris, Thank you for the answer by the way, You don't know if amazon have any tool similar to Heroku to host servers?

Comment: As far as I know the closest Amazon service to Heroku is [Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html). It does deployments to EC2 from Git pushes.